# Kotlin-Native crash call stack miss a frame stack before 'objc2kotlin' function in iOS application

Tags: kotlin-native

My team uses Kotlin-Native to develop our iOS APP.

When a crash happend in kotlin, the crash call stack is not complete. But when I debug the app in XCode, the crash call stack is complete.

When I disconnect XCode and trigger the same crash in the app, and then  connect to XCode the view crash log (***XCode > Window > Devide and Simulator > view device logs***), I find that one stack frame disappears,  the red line in the image below:

[image: the red line stack frame disappear in crash log]

My team found out the 'objc2kotlin' function has a bug: The assembly code of `objc2kotlin` doesn't change the value of `fp(frame pointer, x29)` after pushing `lr(link register, x30)` and `fp(frame pointer, x29)`.

Hope Kotlin-Native team fix the bug quickly, thank you very much.

Comment: File an issue on github? https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues

Comment: Please prefer filing issues on YouTrack: https://kotl.in/issue. Kotlin/Native issue tracking is migrating currently, see details [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/4079)

Comment: @KevinGalligan   My email is 2723364262@qq.com , can you contact with me by email,I can send you something more detail .

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev Due to network problem, I can not access YouTrack (I am in China),

Comment: @KevinGalligan here is my demo project. https://github.com/yuzhiyunAtTencent/KaMPKit,  I only add some code to create a crash in this kotlin function (NativeViewModel.kt: updateBreedFavorite)   , and I add some objc function to call  "updateBreedFavorite",   then  launch the app, disconnect xcode, click heart button in the app, then connect xcode to view crash log, you can find that a stack frame before 'objc2kotlin'  disappear!

Comment: The app of my company has more than ten million netizen, it's really a urgent situation for my team, because crash stack frame loss makes debug diffcult. I hope you can fix this bug, I really appreciate it!@KevinGalligan @ArtyomDegtyarev

Comment: Thank you very much for the report and the investigation, @yuzhiyun! I reproduced the problem, and shared it with the Kotlin/Native team. I will post an update here as soon as it will be available. Just for the record: The issue I've made for this bug is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-44549

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev     Nice!  looking forward to your update

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev  hello   Is there any update recently ?

Comment: Hello, @yuzhiyun! The team agreed that you found the cause correctly. For now, the bugfix is scheduled for the 1.5 version.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev Wow! 

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev Could you please tell me when kotlin 1.5 version will be availabel?

Comment: I got no details at the moment. One should expect it to be released somewhere in spring 2021(according to [this blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/10/new-release-cadence-for-kotlin-and-the-intellij-kotlin-plugin/))

Comment: @KevinGalligan @ ArtyomDegtyarev  Hello, my leader asks me try to build a new kotlin version myself to fix this problem, can you tell me how to use my own kotlin in kampkit project(or other kotlin native project)

Comment: Hello, @yuzhiyun! As you can find in the README.md([here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/kotlin-native)), after you build the compiler from sources, you should specify its location at the `gradle.properties` of your project. KampKit or any other.

Comment: Thank you , In fact I follow the README yesterday,  I install those jdks and then  run "./gradlew :kotlin-native:dist :kotlin-native:distPlatformLibs" at master branch, it's built successful,  next I add dist path to gradle.properties, at last,I run kampkit project in xcode, but this error occured :                                                                                                            
@ArtyomDegtyarev

Comment: > Task :shared:compileKotlinIos FAILED
e: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.DescriptorSerializer$Companion.registerSerializerPlugin(Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/serialization/DescriptorSerializerPlugin;)V
 at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.extensions.SerializationComponentRegistrar$Companion.registerProtoExtensions(SerializationComponentRegistrar.kt:48)

Comment: This error is probably caused by version mismatch between serialization compiler plugin (likely matches your Gradle plugin version) and K/N compiler.

First, please note that you are building K/N from master branch, so it might be more unstable than 1.5.0-M*.
The easiest way to try the fix now is to cherry-pick [the fix](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/commit/c98c790bde1bde1df05f065c804b8e59a1316516) to the branch: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/tree/v1.5.0-M1-fixes.
Then build K/N from it and use it with Gradle plugin 1.5.0-M1.
The fix will be included to 1.5.0-M2.

Comment: @SvyatoslavScherbina  Wow, thank you for the fix, could you tell me how you fix the stack missing bug, I look through the commit you ask me to cherry-pick, but I still can not understand why it's fixed.

Comment: I guess the function names  "enforceFramePointer" makes frame pointer right, but what's the meaning of this function

Comment: Exactly. `enforceFramePointer` just instructs LLVM to use the frame pointer (i.e. update it in the prologue and the epilogue) for the function.

Comment: I cherry-pickd and then  tried to build my own K/N using this command (./gradlew dist distPlatformLibs) , finnaly use it in Kampkit project, but encounter this error, do you konw how to fix this error? Thanks a lot @SvyatoslavScherbina

Comment: w: skipping /Users/yuzhiyun/AndroidStudioProjects/kotlin-native/dist/klib/common/stdlib. The target doesn't match. Expected 'ios_arm64', found [macos_x64]e: Could not find "stdlib"

Comment: @yuzhiyun you've built K/N for macos_x64 target, but are trying to use it for ios_arm64 target.
Please build support for ios_arm64 with `./gradlew ios_arm64PlatformLibs`.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev  Hello, the spec.script_phases in my podspec looks like this: "../gradlew" :shared:syncFramework I wonder where I can find source code of "syncFramework", I want to learn deeper about KN, please show me the code about syncFramework, thank a lot

Comment: @KevinGalligan  hello,please see this cinterop update problem.  thank you !!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67806811/kotlin-native-compilekotlinios-task-fails-beacuse-cinterop-task-can-not-update-w

Comment: @yuzhiyun the most appropriate place is, probably, the GitHub repo. Start with https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/search?q=syncFramework.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev Thank you for the 'syncFramework' link.  Could you please see this cinterop update problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67806811/kotlin-native-compilekotlinios-task-fails-beacuse-cinterop-task-can-not-update-w