# Kotlin-Native CompileKotlinIos task fails beacuse Cinterop task can not update when I change Objective-C code

Tags: kotlin-native, cinterop

@Kevin Galligan My company has a iOS project using Kotlin-Native, and I add a cinterop to the project like this in build.gradle.kts:

```
val CommonInterop by cinterops.creating {
      defFile(project.file("${commonBridgePath}/CommonBridge.def"))
      compilerOpts("-I$commonBridgePath")
    }
```

Everything runs well, the ios project compiles successfully, but when I add a objective-C function
in cinterop and invoke this function in kotlin file, then build ios project, Xcode tells me that   kotlin-native module compile fails.

I know why the compile fails, because compiler does not create corresponding
kotlin function when I add new Objective-c function.

The cinterop task is skipped, In fact the task should not be skipped because objc code changed.
[image]

But after I run the command "gradelw clean", then rebuild the project in xcode, it runs well, objc function is invocked successfully.

Hope Kotlin-Native team can  fix this bug quickly, thanks a lot!

my xcode podspec file look like this:
[image]

and my cinterop configuration looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Do you make changes in the header file, or in the source files?

Comment: Yes, I make changes in 3 files ( 2 objc file and 1 kotlin file ) . I add a objc function declareration  in objc header file and a implementation in objc source file. Then I add  some  kotlin code to invoke this objc function.          Finaly I build the project 
@ArtyomDegtyarev  in Xcode, xcode show errors.      But after I run the command "gradelw clean", then rebuild the project in xcode, it runs well, objc function is invocked successfully.    But it's a waste of time. I have to gradelw clean after I add Cinterop objc function in already existed Cinterop objc class.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm missing how exactly you build the library to interoperate with? As far as I understand, changing headers lead to cinterop tasks re-run(see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43601 for example)

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev    hi, I update two picture in my question.  Maybe picture help you understand my project.         In fact I find that my changing in header file does not lead to cinterop tasks re-run.  But if I run 'gradlew clean',and rebuild project in XCode, the error dismiss and runs well,  my newly added  cinterop objc function is invoked successfully in kotlin files.  So I think there is something wrong with cinterop up-to-update. Compiler cannot find I changed the objc file (as picture 3, I change KYNUderDefault.h and KYNUderDefault.m )and re-run cinterop.

Comment: I did another experiment, after the error occurs, I remove the correspoding cinterop klib file in build directory, and then build ios project in xcode,It runs successfully. Xcode log shows that : cinterop is not up-to-date, so re-run the interop.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev  And please add my account (yuyuyuyuyuyu329@gmail.com) in kotlinlang.slack.com ,thank you very much.   My company wants to keep contact with your team. We are one of top 5 technology in China.

Comment: As I said already, right now it is unclear how exactly your `.m` file change affects your cinterop. Your project structure is not described in the question. Please try to construct a simplified project to share as an archive.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev     hey, bro. I reproduced the bug in a demo project.  https://github.com/yuzhiyunAtTencent/LostStackFrameFixedKampkit    ,please   run the project.  After you run it successfully, add a  new objc function in KYNUserDefault.h and corresponding implement in KYNUserDefault.m ,and finnaly invoke the objc function in  kotlin function named "updateBreedFavorite" in  NativeViewModel.kt.    After you change 3 files,  build this project in XCode again, the log in xcode will tell you (  Task :shared:compileKotlinIos FAILED) ,because NativeViewModel.kt has a unresloved reference :XXX.

Comment: But if I run command './gradlew clean', and rebuild the project, it works successfully. @ArtyomDegtyarev

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev hi, the demo project is provided, please help me find the cause.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem, and transferred the https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43601 ticket to the developers' team. Now I'm waiting for their comment. However, as far as I understand, this problem is not a major one, so the we should be patient.